# How to store indices of an array in an interger?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as follows:

```
$categories = [ 
    0 => 'a',
    1 => 'b',
    2 => 'c',
    3 => 'd',
    4 => 'e',
    5 => 'f',
];
```

Is there a way to use an integer variable that can store multiple indexes of $categories?

Eg:

```
$x = a (an integer number). It means $x contains 0, 1
$x = b (an integer number). It means $x contains 1, 2
etc,
```

Could anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: You need more description about how you get the desired output from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).
Bitwise operators allow evaluation and manipulation of specific bits within an integer.

Comment: Correct. I am trying it.

Answer (score 0):

What about storing instances of an object where the object contains two index properties and a value property